# C++ HashTable Insert Function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a vector of linked-lists, but I'm encountering a problem while implementing an insert function.

Class definition:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class HashTable {
 public:
  HashTable(int size);
  unsigned int hash(string key);
  void insert(string x);

 private:
  vector<list<string> >* table;
```

Class implementation:

```
#include "hashTable.h"
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

HashTable::HashTable(int size) {
  table = new vector<list<string> >(size);
}

HashTable::insert(string x){
   unsigned int index = hash(x);  //left out the hash function for brevity
   table[index].push_back(x);


}
```

I get the error:

```
hashTable.cpp:38:26: error: no viable conversion from 'string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to
      'const value_type' (aka 'const
      std::__1::list<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >')
  table[index].push_back(x);
```

Comment: What is `a` here, which is inserted by push_back?

Comment: Don't `new vector`. There's _never_ a good reason to do that.  Make the vector a member of the class directly.

Comment: include your class definition, please.

Comment: @MooingDuck thank you for the tip. I realize now it makes no sense to dynamically allocate a growable array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 vector<list<string>>* pTable = new vector<list<string>>(100);
 unsigned int index = 3;//Assume that hash("AAA")=3
(*pTable)[index].push_back(string("AAA"));
```

The code above works. Probably you are not passing a proper string object into the list object. And as @Mooing Duck said, make vector a member variable of the class. If needed, you can do the corresponding memory clean up in the destructor of the Hash Table class.